# function that can store 2 var

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to do a calculator and assume I have to click button to insert number to display box. 
For example click 3 and 2  the inputbox display 32 than i need to click "+" button. The add button is to remove the previous number and store it so that i can retype a new number(like a normal calculator do). After that I need to store 3 objects. Which is first input number, "+" and the second number. The reason of store those object is because i need to create the "=" button to send those number to php.

What i need to do and do i need to modify the code. P.S I m using ajax for the "=" function and send it to php. However, I didn't create it yet.

```
var memory = "";
    $("#add").click(function() {
                memory += $show.val() + "+";
                $show.val("");
            });
```

Comment: Maybe share the HTML/CSS etc so that we can see what `#add`, `$show` is, and maybe provide a working demo..?

Comment: @TJ sorry about that.It is the jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/NicholasLui15/9t78jd47/2/

Answer (score 0):

You could store the variables as an object, or array.

```
var memory = {
 var1: 123,
 var2: 123
}
```

or

```
var memory = [var1, var2];
```

then you can grab either one when you need it.

Comment: Sorry i don't get it. So i don't need to use var memory anymore? Use var1 instead? Or type it as memory.var1 ?

Comment: `My problem I don't know how to store 3 objects together. ` This is how you could store those objects together. Do you understand arrays / objects in JS?

Comment: So i don't need to use var memory anymore? Use var1 instead? Or type it as memory.var1 ?

Comment: i tried to put the code in var memory [ mem1, mem2]; but it is not working